# PHP: Cache static navigation

Tags: php, html, caching

On my website there's a static header that includes some graphics & a navigation and such. This content is static and doesn't have to be loaded every time.

Is there a way to put this in a HTML-File, cache it on the clients browser and just tell the browser to include this file at a certain place on the page?

Comment: browses cache whole files only

Comment: What do you need it for?

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility I can think of would be to put the static HTML into a single php file (in which you set some appropiate headers to allow caching) and use JavaScript to perform an Ajax call to load the file into your site. Using jQuery, you could use:

```
$('#navigation').load('navigation.php');
```

This would make the client load the navigation using a separate GET request that can be cached if you set the appropriate headers.

HOWEVER, this is severe overload in my opinion and will probably cause the navigation to load some time after the rest of the page, not to mention compatibility issues with users having JavaScript disabled.

Comment: "here is a bad idea answer". how about not answering? :-)

Comment: He asked for a way to do allow caching, I provided a way to do it ;-) As I don't believe he should implement that, I also provided information on why I believe he shouldn't do it - but he is the one to decide whether it is appropriate in his situation.

Comment: I think there is a major difference between debatable web programming and murder. But we're getting offtopic...

Comment: This approach is popular and not a bad idea, it just may not be worth the downsides. God forbid an answer be right and cautionary. That's like killing the pope.

Comment: Even though you provided an answer for the question, it's still useless answer for a weird question.

Comment: @Anthony: "This approach is popular and not a bad idea" --- if it **is** popular - could you show any more or less known site that loads **static** (by saying *static* here I mean piece of html that is common for every visitor) html dynamically as another ajax request?

Comment: @zerkms - I could, but I don't need to waste my time convincing someone who already has made up their mind.

Comment: @Anthony: it's so predictable. Btw, I'm flexible in my minds and I easily may accept I'm wrong. And I'm surprised that giving a single link is *that hard* for you. It wouldn't be a problem for me to ctrl-c & ctrl-v (*4 keystrokes*) if it was really easy

Answer (score 0):

I agree with TheWolf, that is what I was going to suggest as well.

[Edit: As Anthony pointed out, this will not allow caching the header separately.]
You can simply place the html into it's own .php file and include it server-side when needed using:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

The "header" html will be included in the page's html and that will be cached by the browser (assuming the proper cache headers are sent). This is the most common method of including conditional content in php.

What is the reason for wanting to cache the header separately? If your application is generating a standard web page, then loading the header separately via Javascript will be slower. Any bandwidth saving would likely be negligible.

If you decide to dynamically load the content with Javascript, a few things you can do to enhance the end-user experience is to:

- Place your Javascript at the bottom of your template above the ending  tag. This will allow the browser to begin loading other assets required for page rendering first.
- If possible, prime the area you're injecting the content into by sizing the container to the proper height and width in your template. This will prevent the page from "jumping" due to the additional space needed by the header.

Comment: "This will allow the browser to begin loading other assets required for page rendering first." --- and now user won't see navigation until the page is completely loaded. Such a great UX. Bravo.

Comment: This won't cache the header portion on its own.